# Ubuntu Tweak doesn't want to install

Tags: apt, 15.04, ppa, repository

I use that commands in Ubuntu 15.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get this error message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Because of this error I can't install Ubuntu Tweak...

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please don't double post.

Answer (score 3):

[`ppa:tualatrix/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) doesn't (currently) contain any package for Ubuntu 15.04. The warning messages in your question are normal behaviour in such a case.

As a remedy, you can

- remove Tualatrix' PPA and use the [GetDeb App repository](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/vivid/apps/getdeb/ubuntu-tweak):

  ```
  wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu vivid-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
  ```

  <sup>([source](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/getdeb_apps?dist=vivid))</sup>
- switch to the `trusty` packages from Tualatrix' PPA, since that seems to be the [latest upstream version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+download) anyway:

  1. Open the software properties settings (`gksudo software-properties-gtk`, if you can't find it in the system settings overview).
  2. Select the entry for Tualatrix' PPA (binary) and click on the button titled *Edit*.
  3. Replace `vivid` with `trusty` and click *OK*.

     [image: software source property editor]
  4. Repeat step 2 and 3 with the entry for Tualatrix' PPA (source).
  5. Click *Close*.

In both cases you need to run `sudo apt-get update` to update the newly configured package sources.